# Embedding a base64 image to a DocuSign template (REST API)

Tags: base64, docusignapi

I'm currently developing a system for a client that essentially collects data from a person and adds it to a docusign template via the rest api. I was just wondering if it's possible to embed a base64 image into the template?

Comment: Ever get this to work? I'm using an HTML envelope and the `<img />` element won't render properly

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add base64 image also as a document to a template or an envelope. Supported file formats in DocuSign are available [here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-supported-file-formats)